# sql insert to table realted to another table and constant values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have 2 SQL tables, table1 and table2.

table1 has two columns and I want to insert values to these columns.
one of the columns should get a static value and the other column should get a value that is a result of a query from table2.

If I wanted to insert the static data separately I would do:

```
INSERT INTO table1(login_id)
VALUES ('1234');
```

and if I wanted to insert the dynamic value separately I would do:

```
INSERT INTO table1(user_uuid)
SELECT users_uuid FROM table2 where first_name like 'ortal';
```

How can insert both values to table1 in one action?

If I try the first query I get:

```
11:20:45    INSERT INTO table1(login_id ,user_uuid) VALUES ('1234') Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1   0.000 sec

INSERT INTO `users`.`table1` (`login_id`) VALUES ('1234');

ERROR 1364: 1364: Field 'user_uuid' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: Isn't that what @murelnik 's answer tells you how to solve?

Answer (score 9):

You can add the constants to your select list and treat them a columns:

```
INSERT INTO table1(user_uuid, login_id)
SELECT users_uuid, '1234' FROM table2 WHERE first_name LIKE 'ortal';
```

Comment: From the code you've provided you're inserting data into table1? Your issue is that user_uuid appears to be a NOT NULL field which means you have to populate this when inserting other data. The code that @mureinik provided does that for you. If you're talking about inserting data into table2 then you need to correct your original question.